# IE Tooltip Displaying on negative Hover

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I'm in the process of making of a big pack of Tooltips with CSS3 animations and transitions, which they all work, even in IE with fallback so they just display above the text.

I'm using the following to display the actual tooltip.

```
.tooltip span {
width:200px;
height:auto;
padding: 5px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -110px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
border: 5px solid #57a0d8;
background:#FFF;
text-indent: 0px;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
bottom: -120px;
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

The rest is just simply animation. Now when I hover 120px below the actual tooltip in IE, it displays that tooltip. This is because of

```
bottom:-120px;
```

in the CSS.

I'm using jQuery to try and override this issue using the following:

**EDIT:**

**The new JS:**

```
  $(function() {
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9)
    {     
              $('.tooltip span').hide(); 
          $(".tooltip").hover(function() {
$(this).find('span').addClass(".bottomfix");
}, function() {
$(this).find('span').removeClass(".bottomfix");
});
    }
  });
```

**The new CSS fix:**

```
.bottomfix {
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Hopefully some useful information!
The code works, except the CSS change. I must be doing something wrong. Is there any possible solution I could change in the CSS to fix this for IE, or a solution for using jQuery?

**EDIT 2:**

It works fine in IE8 - but still shows the tooltip when hovering within the 120px bottom boundary in IE9. Confused isn't the word!

Help is much appreciated, I hope this is enough to give you an idea what I mean!

Comment: Just a comment, maybe you can use $ or jQuery. You don't have to mix them.

Comment: True, I've edited the post now to what I changed it to in my js. Still no luck but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change following lines:

```
jQuery(this).addClass(".tooltip span");
```

to

```
jQuery(this).addClass("tooltip span");
```

Don't use `.className` with `addClass` or `removeClass` use only the name without dot like `className`.

Comment: I think the `span` he meant was a tag name, not a class name. In that case, your code would not work.

Comment: `span` is the HTML tag. but again, thanks for the help so far, i'm getting slowly closer to solving it!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(this).addClass(".tooltip span");
```

To

```
$(this).find('span').addClass("newStyle");
```

Same to the `removeClass`

Also,

Change your style name from `.tooltip span` to `.newStyle` in your CSS.

Comment: I made a new CSS class called `.bottomfix { bottom:0}` and then changed the js to what you stated above but no luck so far. I will edit the code above in the OP!

Comment: As @TheVillageIdiot said, you need to remove the dot when you call `removeClass` and `addClass`. Try that again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use `display:none` instead of `opacity:0;`. Write like this:

```
.tooltip span{
 display:none;
}
```